# Run Scheduled Task in Windows Batch File?

Tags: windows, batch-file

My issue exists in another question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24897596/call-a-batch-on-a-share-with-references-to-local-drives). I'm wondering whether it's possible to activate a scheduled task on one server from the command line of another server. I do not want to use psexec as it is known to be an enabled of malware and viruses. Does anyone know if this is possible?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the the commands below to stop and start tasks remotely.

Stop:

```
schtasks /end /s <machine name> /U Username /P password /tn <task name>
```

Start:

```
schtasks /run /s <machine name> /U Username /P password /tn <task name>
```

Comment: Awesome. This worked. I also utilize the information here to have the batch wait for the scheduled task to complete: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20261639/how-do-you-wait-on-a-task-scheduler-task-to-finish-in-a-batch-file-or-c